# Images assets landscape and portrait for universal devices and sizes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, image, ipad, landscape

I am completely new for Image assets in **xcode**. I am creating a sample project, In that I have story screen, It contains the **UIPageViewController** with images. I added 320*480px,750*1134px,1242*2208px images. In portrait modeworking fine, But the problem is, If I **rotate** the device from stretching to **landscape** the **image is stretching**. I tried with **xcode** image assets options. I saw different sizes(**Refer image**) while selecting the **width and height like Any&compact, Any&Regular** etc. I am not able to understand what are the size to add at 1*,2*,3*.

**More details:**
project supported version is **iOS >=8**. support iPhone and iPad both **landscape** and **portrait**.

Do we need to add all these images.

If we use iPhone and iPad, Why we need to use **width** and **height** attributes.

Can you help me.

Any one explain the below image and it's sizes.

[image]

Comment: Yes if you are adding an application which is Universal, supporting IOS >=6.0 and device > iPhone 4 then you need to add all these. But you are asking for the splash screen and icons?
Your screen shows something else, can you share what are you doing?

Comment: I am adding overview of project in UIPageviewController. Reference image http://1u88jj3r4db2x4txp44yqfj1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/linkedin-students-intro.jpg . Can you share the sizes. This is not splash screen.